# Поместить картинку за текстовый блок

Tags: html, css

Сама картинка должна быть под текстом, оставшаяся часть выходить из под текстового блока

```css
.info {
  position: relative;
  background: #eef9f9;
  min-height: 800px;
}

.text-wrap {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 2;
}

.text {
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info__object {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="text-wrap">
    <div class="text">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Взобравшись рыбными алфавит собрал безопасную скатился! Коварный большой вершину текстов заманивший речью, живет деревни имеет, о рукописи его рыбного предупреждал.
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Ее моей своего буквенных рукописи рыбного там над заглавных ведущими текст живет, свой последний путь гор великий рукопись, коварных она?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="info__object">
    <img src="https://www.manyakdental.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/c1099-archpoint-GRAPHIC-tooth-212x300.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.info {
  position: relative;
  background: #eef9f9;
  min-height: 800px;
}

.text-wrap {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 2;
}

.text {
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info__object {
 
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="text-wrap">
    <div class="text">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Взобравшись рыбными алфавит собрал безопасную скатился! Коварный большой вершину текстов заманивший речью, живет деревни имеет, о рукописи его рыбного предупреждал.
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Ее моей своего буквенных рукописи рыбного там над заглавных ведущими текст живет, свой последний путь гор великий рукопись, коварных она?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="info__object">
    <img src="https://www.manyakdental.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/c1099-archpoint-GRAPHIC-tooth-212x300.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: поправил вопрос, некорректно сформулировал в начале